# Assignment expression in a while loop

Tags: python, regex

```
m = re.match(pattern, text)
while m := p.search(text, m.end()):
    # do with match
```

Does the `m.end()` refer to the previous match `m` so that the search starts from the end of the previous match? I read [PEP-572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#capturing-condition-values), and there's a section that talks specifically about regex matches, but not with a `while` loop. I understand that `m` is available in the body of the loop, that's not the question here.

Comment: yes, it is updated, right there: `m :=  ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, the previous value of `m` is available outside the loop body?

Comment: what do you mean the previous value of `m`? No, there is only one `m` variable here. as written, it would be in the global scope

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought it was pretty clear from the code sample, but I've edited the post to clarify my question.

Comment: in this case, assuming `p` is a `re.Pattern` object, then `m` will always have a value of `None` after the end of the loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, "_the search starts from the end of the previous match_" wouldn't happen?

Comment: I don't know how to say this any more clearly. There is only one `m` variable. At the beginning of the code, you assign to it before the while loop. `m = re.match(pattern, text)`. Then the `while` loop executes, and the very same variable previously defined gets re-assigned by `m := p.search(text, m.end())`. The first iteration *uses the value that was assigned in the first statment*. So yes, the search starts from the end of the previous match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. I did a small experiment that proved what I was after.

```
def do(x):
    print(f'x in do = {x}')
    return (x + 1) if x < 5 else None
    
x = 0
while (x := do(x)) is not None:
    print(f'x in while = {x}')
```

Output:

```
x in do = 0
x in while = 1
x in do = 1
x in while = 2
x in do = 2
x in while = 3
x in do = 3
x in while = 4
x in do = 4
x in while = 5
x in do = 5
```

Thus, the answer to my question is "yes, the previous value of the variable is available to the `while` loop even after the body is exited". Actually, just like a regular variable, the assignment variable is in scope for the rest of the function from the point it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes the text will always start with a match, otherwise, the `while` cause would raise a type error, since `re.match` always tries to match at the beginning, unlike `re.search` which will search the whole string (unless of course you use an anchor).

So yes, it basically keeps searching from the end of the last matching position, finding each subsequent non-overlapping match. You can see this happen like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "foo some other stuff foo again foo foofofoo"
>>> p = re.compile("foo")
>>> m = p.match(s) # assumes it always matches at the beginning
>>> while print(m) or (m:= p.search(s, m.end())):
...     pass
...
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(21, 24), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(31, 34), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(35, 38), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(40, 43), match='foo'>
```

So the actual body of the while-loop will only have access to every match starting with the second match.

Note that in this case, you probably just want to use `.finditer` and a for-loop

```
>>> for m in p.finditer(text):
...     print(m)
...
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(21, 24), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(31, 34), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(35, 38), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(40, 43), match='foo'>
```

Unless the body is updating `m`. Note, in this case, the for-loop *would* have access to the first match, unlike the body of the while loop. if you wanted to skip the first one, you could always do:

```
>>> it = p.finditer(text)
>>> next(it)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
>>> for m in it:
...     print(m)
...
<re.Match object; span=(21, 24), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(31, 34), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(35, 38), match='foo'>
<re.Match object; span=(40, 43), match
```